# Word Properties not in Summary tab

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, doc

I've been struggling to set a customProperties (and built in properties) for a word document through the COM interface and just succeeded. However the properties are only visible from within Word, not in the summary tab.

**issue**

OK, so with that opening statement, I was a little misleading to simplify the problem. I'm using the netOffice wrapper to interact with the word interop components (makes deployment real easy), it's used to automate a mailmerge through an ASP.Net portal. I use the same to add the documents ID into the CustomDocumentProperties.

This ID is then later picked up by a console application, which uses DSOFile.dll to acesss the OLE/Summary properties.

Now although I can see my custom databaseID field in word, it's not in the summary tab (see below), which I presume is where DSOFile takes them from, this happens with both built in and custom properties. I'm in the dark about how these two differ or why they loose synchronisation.

**tests**

From the testing I've done, I was surprised that adding/changing  properties then saving them doesn't fix the problem with the document properties. However saving them to a new file will update summary. Furthermore there's a notable delay after saving where the summary tab doesn't even appear, It almost looks like a background process is responsible for updating them.

I'd be interested to hear anything about how summary properties differ from those stored within the word document if you don't have a solution for me.

[image: shows that properties aren't set in the summary tab, but are set in word..]

In case it's important, my issue today with adding the properties wasn't the typical saving when the document wasn't "dirty". Rather I kept the template open as well as the completed document and needed to activate it before saving.

Let me know if I've missed any important details, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a consolidation of some comments on this Question)

It is unlikely that you will be able to view Custom Properties in the file system's property viewer while the Document is open in Word.

This is probably a safety mechanism to prevent simultaneous updating of properties by two separate processes.

OLE Structured Storage files are OLE objects. They are only closed when the OLE reference count to the object is reduced to 0.

So, if for example some code is using DSOFile to add a property and is not releasing the OLE object, the file remains open. Other processes trying to update the file may behave differently from how they would behave if the OLE object was released and the fie was "closed".